# Double click is binding to parent or sibling element when I double click the particular element which will be hiding on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have declared two div one after other in layer format, which means "DIV2 (#myDiv2) will be placed over the DIV1 (#myDiv1). For single click on DIV2, it has to be hide. It works fine. But when I double click the DIV2, DIV2 gets hide by the first click of that double click event and then double click event also binding to the DIV1. I don't know how it happens. 
My requirement is when I double click the DIV2, DIV2 has to hide and then single click event only needs to bind for the DIV1.

```js
$("#myDiv2").click(function(e) {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
});
$("#myDiv1").dblclick(function(e) {
  alert("DIV 1 double clicked");
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1" style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
<br/>
<div id="myDiv2" style="background-color:green; width:100px;margin-top:-80px;height:40px">I am Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dblclick` event queues the `click` event and check for the target element. The visibility hidden interferes and the second immediate click is fired on target element.

One solution is to, unbind and bind the `dblclick` event with a timeout after hiding the second `div`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6eyxrh6/6/)

```
$("#myDiv1").on('dblclick', runOnDoubleClick);

$("#myDiv2").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();   
    $("#myDiv1").off('dblclick');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myDiv1").on('dblclick', runOnDoubleClick)
    }, 300);
});

function runOnDoubleClick()
{
    alert("DIV 1 double clicked");
    $("#myDiv2").show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Have updated the answer. the time out is required to suspend the current click queue.

Comment: yes. I mentioned it as one solution. not the only :)

Comment: @Moniecorleone Already I knew this type of workaround fix for that double click.

Comment: Can anyone explain me the exact reason behind this behavior of double click?

Comment: @JohnR the only idea I have is: _jQuery saves coordinates of last click. If second click is after short period of time and approximately in the same point of screen, then it is double click. What element was double-clicked is determined only on second click by second click's `event.target`_.

Comment: @Regent Tq for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the click events confused, try this:

```
$("#myDiv2").dblclick(function(e) {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
});
$("#myDiv1").click(function(e) {
  alert("DIV 1 double clicked");
});
```

Comment: Nope, the problem is: you click first time on `#myDiv2`, it becomes hidden. All is OK. Then you click again (after very short period of time) at the same point of screen (which is in `#myDiv1` now). And `dblclick` for `#myDiv1` is triggered, even though you have clicked on `#myDiv1` only once.

Comment: I just copied your source code into jsbin and I can't seem to find that bug... http://jsbin.com/qatipahati
try hard reloading or something, I thing that my browser cache tends to mess things up even though they are working fine...

Comment: 1. It's not my source code. 2. I do see this bug in your example. I use Opera 30.0.

Comment: you're on your own, kid :(